# Should I use 'isn't there' to show no food that I have been craving for?

Tags: definite-article, countable-nouns, dummy-pronouns

> "When the food you are craving for isn't there, the last choice you have is Maggi."

Is my grammar correct? Or can you change my sentence so it will be better than mine? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar is incorrect. "Crave" does not take "for." The use of the progressive is grammatical but a bit unidiomatic.

"When the food you crave is not there, ..."